# Why swagger array produces string instead an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, koa

I have a `.yaml` file where I described my schema:

```
produces: 
  - application/json
consumes:
  - multipart/form-data
```

...

```
/events:
   post:
      parameters:
      - in: formData
        name: members
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
        required: false
        description: An array with event members
```

That's how my UI looks like:
[image: example]

I am handling my request with `koa` `(node.js)` and `http-body-parser`.

But even if i have `type: array` my response looks like a 
`members:` `'"data","lorem","ipsum"'` and type of it is a `string`. Can I send an array to my server from swagger docs?

Comment: This might be [this bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4146).

Comment: Please check https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/